# How to nest addmargin?

Tags: koma-script

I have a quoted text on a page - with a margin set in - and under this text I need to place the description of the source, which should be indented again. If I nest the`addmargin` command, I get the error `! LaTeX Error: \begin{addmargin} on input line 28 ended by \end{addmarging}.`

How can I nest `addmargin`?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{paper=      
    128.5mm:198.4mm, %(5,06" x 7,91")  %ziel
    titlepage=true,
    DIV=9,  %ziel kleines buch 
    fontsize=12pt,
}


\begin{document}
% Widmung
\newpage
{     %begin widmung 
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{addmargin}[1cm]{0.1cm}
        \flushleft
        \vspace*{3\baselineskip}
        %              
        \textit{%
            Aber Du kennst ja noch gar nicht Deine kleine Geschichte. 
            zugegeben oder geleugnet werden muß) sie wäre nichts.
            }

        {
            \begin{addmargin}[4cm]{0.1cm}
            \flushleft
            \vspace*{1\baselineskip}

            Franz  

            Briefe  

            Nacht vom 4. zum 5. 1912 (Seite 156)
            \end{addmarging}  %kafka
    }

\end{addmargin}
%          }
%\vspace*{\fill}        
%\newpage
}           %end widmung 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\end{addmarging}` with `\end{addmargin}`

Comment: Thank you - a really stupid typo, which I could not see! My bad!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was just a typo.